# Error in file is :- java.io.FileNotFoundException: \files\storetime.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, ioexception

i am using eclipse for develop the java desktop application and working with file but got the above error

my code is as following please try to help me how to give path in eclipse and also get same problem to load image from the given task

i have put the "files" folder out side the "src" folder

how to give  path dynamically

my code is ass following

```
          public int getTimeId()
{
    LOG.info("The File name is :- " + fileName);
    LOG.info("The path is :- ");
    int count=0;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    try
    {
        fileInputStream=new FileInputStream("/files/storetime.txt");
        objectInputStream=new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        while(objectInputStream.readObject()!=null)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in file is :- " + e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in class not found :- " + e);
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: You're currently specifying an *absolute* filename. Did you perhaps just mean `"files/storetime.txt"` so it's relative to the current working directory?

Comment: here is also one exception come :- Error in file is :- java.io.EOFException please give solution of this also

Comment: Well what research have you done? 9 minutes (between my comment and yours) really isn't enough effort into working out why you're getting that exception and trying to fix it....

Comment: your comment is used full me to solve my problem which i have describe in my question successfully but now new error is occur which i have describe above in comment and it's come when i am initializing the object of the ObjectInputStream..........Thank you so much for help me to solve my main problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing the absolute path by prep-ending `/` in the path. It means `root` directory in Unix file system. so, you have to give a relative path of the file from the current directory.You can put `files` directory in the root directory of your project folder and use

```
fileInputStream=new FileInputStream("files/storetime.txt");
```

So, it will be picked up

Comment: We do a agree that the fullpath can also be used (if it is not to long - that just looks ugly). Also the fullpath can avoid some confusion, that can arise with relative paths?

Comment: The Full path causes problem when you are deploying the applicaiton in some other environment since the app will expect the same directory structure. Further more, any application should be self-contained, that's the good design. If you understand how relative path works, then there will not be any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Use FileInputStream(new File("files/storetime.txt")); don't use /file  -> it will check for /file partition in linux as /root